# OSError: [WinError 10049] L’adresse demandée n’est pas valide dans son contexte

Tags: python, winapi, pysnmp

I'm tring to get snmp traps but i get OSError: [WinError 10049] error can anyone  please help me to solve this problem , here is my entire code:

```
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import ntfrcv
snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()

TrapAgentAddress='10.17.92.2' #Trap listerner address
Port= 163  #trap listerner port
print("Agent is listening SNMP Trap on "+TrapAgentAddress+" , Port : " +str(Port))
print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------')
config.addTransport(
    snmpEngine,
    udp.domainName + (1,),
    udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode((TrapAgentAddress, Port))
)

#Configure community here
config.addV1System(snmpEngine, 'my-area', 'public')

def cbFun(snmpEngine, stateReference, contextEngineId, contextName,
          varBinds, cbCtx):
    print("Received new Trap message")
    for name, val in varBinds:        
        print('%s = %s' % (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))

ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(snmpEngine, cbFun)

snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)  

try:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
except:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
    raise
```

and here is the Traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oussama.belhadje.stg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\carrier\asyncore\dgram\base.py", line 55, in openServerMode
    self.socket.bind(iface)
OSError: [WinError 10049] L’adresse demandée n’est pas valide dans son contexte
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/oussama.belhadje.stg/Desktop/pysnmp/snmp_trap_receiver.py", line 15, in <module>
    udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode((TrapAgentAddress, Port))
  File "C:\Users\oussama.belhadje.stg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\carrier\asyncore\dgram\base.py", line 57, in openServerMode
    raise error.CarrierError('bind() for %s failed: %s' % (iface, sys.exc_info()[1],))
pysnmp.carrier.error.CarrierError: bind() for ('10.17.92.2', 163) failed: [WinError 10049] L’adresse demandée n’est pas valide dans 
son contextecaused by <class 'OSError'>: [WinError 10049] L’adresse demandée n’est pas valide dans son contexte
```

Comment: Please edit your post to provide the full stack trace error.

Comment: Please EDIT your post to include the stack trace, comments are not the place for them due to formatting and character limits.

Comment: I've not used pysnmp personally, but the fact that you are getting a bind error and using a method called openServerMode suggests that you are using the wrong method here. Bind would be called to open a listening socket to accept incoming connections, not connect to a remote system as I think the intention here is.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a port smaller than 1024 requires administrator permissions to listen on.

Thus, you will have to run this Python code as administrator on Windows.

BTW, to listen to TRAP and NOTIFICATION you should bind to port 162, not 163.